# Taking photo intent with cropped image preview

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop, photo

I am making an application where I need to take a photo and then crop a 100x100 area from it. Right now I am making an intent call for taking a picture and then I create a CropActivity that will crop it.

I was wondering if default photo application could be set crop taken picture and show a border on screen to identify an area which is supposed to be cropped before taking the picture.

Maybe with some extras? I dont know. I search ong enought, but didnt find anything to do this in one step WITH preview.

(please do not post solutions, how to crop image separately and without a preview, I already know)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if default photo application could be set crop taken picture and show a border on screen to identify an area which is supposed to be cropped

There are well over 1 billion Android devices, spread across over a thousand device models. Those have hundreds of "default photo applications", as a mix of pre-installed apps and other camera apps that users installed and made be their default.

[None have to support any sort of crop-related extras](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

Comment: Yes and I would like to know if there are some extras, that is supported from SOME applications. I would like to support this option even if it may not work on all devices.

Comment: @arenaq: Since you cannot tell whether any given device has a default camera application that supports these extras, the only sensible choice is for you to not bother with them.

Comment: Since you can easily check what data is given back in intent (fullsize image, null), you can respond to it accordingly. If you dont have any constructive answer, please, do not bother to post in this thread.

Comment: @arenaq: "Since you can easily check what data is given back in intent (fullsize image, null), you can respond to it accordingly" -- first, you do not know what a full size image is, as camera resolutions vary. Second, you do not know whether the image that you get back is either the result of a crop (where the user did not crop much), the result of the user saying "I do not want to crop", or the fact that the camera app did not offer crop support. "do not bother to post in this thread" -- this answer is to provide advice to anyone making these mistakes.

Comment: My application works with fixed image dimension only. Other dimensions are off the table. So if intent is returning image with different dimensions than defined, it can respond to it by using libraries (that I already use). I just want to give users the option to use whatever software that have installed, which supports cropping an image.

Comment: @arenaq: "My application works with fixed image dimension only. Other dimensions are off the table." -- you have no way to force a third-party camera application to take a picture at a particular resolution. "So if intent is returning image with different dimensions than defined, it can respond to it by using libraries (that I already use)." -- since the user will not be able to hit your "fixed image dimension" in most cases even when there is some sort of built-in crop option, you will wind up using that library for the vast majority of images.

Answer (score 0):

You can save path of image(i.e. Uri) in a string then putExtra this with your intent as:
String mUri = "android.media.whatever";
Intent mIntent.putExtra("imgUri", mUri);
 and then in receiver side you can get the image using:

Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra("imgUri");

Comment: This answer is not for this question, by mistake i post this, so plz ignore this